# How to run CodeRAD 2 in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I am learning CodeRAD but am using netbeans as my ide. I created a CodeRAD project from  https://start.codenameone.com but when i open it in my ide it has problems. I understand that from the tutorial they are using intellj. Can any one please help me on how i will start this using netbeans.

i downloaded all the required dependancies but still getting this error

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project coderad-common: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "kind" because "sym" is null -> [Help 1]
```

Am using apache netbeans IDE 14,
and java jdk 18, and the maven version downloaded in my netbeans is maven 4.47.
Yes in deed i did select netbeans as my ide before i download my template.

Comment: [1] You definitely selected _NetBeans_ as your IDE for the download, right? (The default is _Intellij IDEA_.) [2] Update your question to specify your versions of NetBeans, Maven and Java. Without that information others cannot attempt to replicate/resolve your problem. [3] That tutorial is using JDK 11, so to minimize potential issues it would be preferable to use that version if possible.

Comment: Thanks for that, i will try because i already have jdk 18

Comment: This worked for me: [1] Download the _Bare-bones Java App_ to **D:/CodenameOne**, and unzip the file. [2] Configure NetBeans 15 to use JDK 11.0.12 and restart it. [3] In NetBeans use **File > Open Project** to open the downloaded and unzipped project **D:/CodenameOne/MyApp**. [4] Right-click that project in the **Projects** panel and select **Build** from the context menu. Maven downloaded whatever was needed and built the project, and eventually a _Login_ screen for Codename One opened in the browser, as expected. Does that work for you as well?

Comment: I have updated the start.codenameone.com server to use the latest archetype version now which resolves a few compatibility issues with newer JDKs.  Please try generating a fresh project and see if this resolves it for you.  I was able to generate a CodeRAD starter project for netbeans and build/run it fine using JDK17+NetBeans 12.